# ComponentDidMount twice

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I wrote a search class but searched only once for each time.

ComponentDidMount seems to run in searchExtend once only once

Is there a solution to this problem?

```
searchMe = (search) => {
    this.refs.searchField.blur(false);
    this.setState({output: <SearchExtend name={search} />})
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          ref="searchField"
          style={styles.input}
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={this.handleSearch}
        >
        </TextInput>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.submitButton}
          onPress={
            ()=>this.searchMe(this.state.search)
          }
        >
        <Text>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          {this.state.output}
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }
```

searchExtend Class is:

```
componentDidMount(){

      return fetch('http://example.com/search.php' , {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({

          // Getting the search.
          search: this.props.name
        })
       }).then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
         this.setState({
           //isLoading: false,
           dataSource: responseJson
         }, function() {
           // In this block you can do something with new state.
         });
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });

   }


return(
      <FlatList
        Vertically

        data={this.state.dataSource}

        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
        renderItem={({item}) =>

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={()=> this.onPress(item.subCategory, item)}>

            <Image
                  source={{uri: item.icon}}
                  style={{width:100, height:100}}
            />

          </TouchableOpacity>
        }
        numColumns={1}
        onEndReachedThreshold={120}
        onEndReached={this.endReach()}
        keyExtractor={(item)=>item.ID}
      />
    )
```

The rest of the sections and styles were removed because they were not related to the question

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: componentDidMount is a lifecycle event and will only fire one time when the component has finished mounting. If you want to run you fetch code again, you should put it in it's own method, handleSearch, and call that from the input change event.

Comment: If I do not use componentDidMount, onEndReached will run repeatedly(again and again)